# Collapsible div with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a mobile app. I have the following dummy code. At the moment it is collapsing from bottom to top i.e when I click on the first 3 links, questions gets hidden and you only see the answers.

Is it possible to show both the question and answer when you click on the link. Preferably with just CSS if not javascript.

```css
.faq ul li {
  display:block;
  padding:5px;
  line-height: 8;
}

.faq ul li div {
  display:none;
}

.faq ul li div:target {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="faq">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#question1">Question 1</a>   
      <div id="question1">Answer 1 </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#question2">Question 2</a>
      <div id="question2">Answer 2 </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#question3">Question 3</a>
      <div id="question3">Answer 3 </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#question4">Question 4</a>
      <div id="question4">Answer 4 </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#question5">Question 5</a>
      <div id="question5">Answer 5 </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#question6">Question 6</a>
      <div id="question6">Answer 6 </div>
    </li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

**Fiddle: jsfiddle.net/4sKD3/858**

Comment: They both are visible, but only issue is they both are not in the viewport.

Comment: This fiddle is working properly. It displays both question and answer

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, it seems to be working perfectly fine for me.

Comment: If i want to add more lists for e.g. 10, when I click on the first couple of links the questions gets hidden only the answers are visible. Maybe its the way the target works. Just wanted to know if there was a way to modify the default to make both visible

Comment: @Ray I understood your problem. Please have a look at my answer and tell if that works.

Comment: Sorry guys i posted the wrong fiddle link one sec

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4sKD3/858/ this is the right one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the target this way, make the `id` and `href` same for the `<a>` and use the `+` adjacent selector to make it work for you.

```css
.faq ul li {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 8;
}
.faq ul li div {
  display: none;
}
.faq ul li a:target + a + div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="faq">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#question1" id="question1">Question 1</a> <a href="#close1" id="close1">Close</a>
      <div>Answer 1</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#question2" id="question2">Question 2</a>
      <div>Answer 2</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#question3" id="question3">Question 3</a>
      <div>Answer 3</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#question4" id="question4">Question 4</a>
      <div>Answer 4</div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#question5" id="question5">Question 5</a>
      <div>Answer 5</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#question6" id="question6">Question 6</a>
      <div>Answer 6</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now having the `<a>` as the target with the `id` too, it jumps in the question with the answer displayed next to it. Hope this is what you were expecting. I changed the `id` to `<a>` and used the adjacent selector for targetting the `<div>` this way:

```
.faq ul li a:target + div
```

Browser compatibility, every browser in the world! `:P`

Comment: Sure man while we at it is there a way to hide it when i click on the question with just css?

Comment: Yes, just put another link to `#`. Ha ha... That hides it. Else add another `id` with `#q1` and give it in the same place. As simple as that. Do you want me to do it @Ray?

Comment: That would be great if you can do for the first one :)

Comment: @Ray Sure... Doing it.

Comment: @Ray Have a look now.

Comment: Is it possible to hide it with clicking on the question without close link? I got the javascript solution but couldn't figure out with CSS

Comment: @Ray Use a BIG `<a href="#close-1">` LoL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88367/discussion-between-ray-and-praveen-kumar).